# How to configure "cvt" properly?

Tags: display, xrandr

I'm trying to add a new resolution to my screen by:

```
cvt 1920 980 60
```

which produces

```
# 1920x980 59.92 Hz (CVT) hsync: 60.94 kHz; pclk: 156.00 MHz 
 Modeline "1920x980_60.00"  156.00  1920 2040 2240 2560  980 983 993 1017 -hsync +vsync
```

then I'm feeding it to `xrandr` to add a new res and update the res accordingly.

I'm currently using res 1920x1080. When I update it to 1920x980 I was expecting bottom few centimetres go black but instead I'm getting a black horizontal strip on top.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to adjust the position of the screen using the `--panning` option in `xrandr`. This option allows you to specify the size of the virtual screen and the position of the visible screen within it.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x980_60.00" 156.00  1920 2040 2240 2560  980 983 993 1017 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode <your display output> "1920x980_60.00"
xrandr --output <your display output> --mode "1920x980_60.00" --panning 1920x1080+0+80
```

You can adjust the `+0+80` part of the `--panning` option to reposition the screen until the black strip is no longer visible.

Comment: changing +0+80 isn't doing anything at all.

Comment: Hmmm... try this `xrandr --output <your display output> --mode "1920x980_60.00" --pos 0+80`